# giving two choices in django without creating another class and foreignkey

Tags: python, django

let's say I want each post to have category but I know there will be only two categories. I don't want to create another model named class category and foreignkey it. is there a different way to do it? each post have either category1 or category2. I want to put this choice in post model field.

Comment: Something like a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` with `choices` set may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django has `field.choices`, you can use it in your existing model.
This example is taken from django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
    ('FR', 'Freshman'),
    ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
    ('JR', 'Junior'),
    ('SR', 'Senior'),
]
```

here first value for ex 'FR' is a value that will be set as value to variable and second value 'Freshman' is a human-readable value that you will see, so if you choose 'Freshman' then variable will contain value 'FR', each tuple represents a choice, in your case, you will have only two tuple.

here is an example to use field.choices
from django.db import models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    ]
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in (self.JUNIOR, self.SENIOR)
```

Check django field.choices https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices